# Ambiguous and inconstant order of method call

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods, bluej

I am writing a program that uses two paint methods to produce output based on the "painting" produced by the previous "paint" method. There are two methods, draw1 and draw2, with the initial configuration given using draw1 and then draw2 is used to generate output for the next line. When I execute my code, however, I encounter strange errors regarding the order in which the methods defined are called. I added several print() statements to my code in an attempt to understand this, but this has only aggravated the problem, since the addition of the print() statement seems to affect the order of the method call itself.

Here is the code (still a very basic version)-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Processor extends JFrame
{
static int x=1;
public Processor()
{
    setTitle("Automaton");
    setSize(1000,1000);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    System.out.println("In constructor");
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if(x==1)
        draw(g);
    else if(x==2)    
        draw2(g);        
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
    System.out.println("In Draw");
}//This is the initial setting.

public void draw2(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(500,22,50,50);
    System.out.println("In Draw2");
}

public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Component component) 
{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    component.paint(g);
    return image;
}

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    System.out.println("Start");
    BufferedImage image;
    Processor t=new Processor();
    System.out.println("Middle");
    image=toBufferedImage(t);
    System.out.println("End");
    //Color myColor=new Color(image.getRGB(500,500));

    x=2;
    image=toBufferedImage(t);
}

}
```

When I run this code, I get the following output along with an empty, white screen-

```
Start
In Draw
In constructor
Middle
In Draw
In Draw
End
In Draw2
```

Two questions come to my mind from this

1) Why does the execution of

```
image=toBufferedImage(t);
```

lead to draw() being called twice?

2) As evidenced from the "In draw2" line, the program has entered draw2(). Then why am I getting a blank and white screen? (Without the square).

Moreover, when I try to add another print() statement, the order of method calls itself changes. I have not added in the code and output for that due to the excessive length of the question, but I would like to know if there is some explanation for this.

P.S I am using the BlueJ Environment for running my code.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code execution using a debugger?

Comment: The method "public void paint(Graphics g)" is already defined in JFrame (by java.awt.Window) do you override it by intention? - At least this is the reason why "In Draw" is printed directly after "Start" because your call "setVisible(true)" also calls "paint(Graphics g)".

Comment: @SWoeste I have overridden paint by intention. Thanks for your comment, one part of the puzzle is solved. However, what I'd really like to know is how draw() was able to call itself (as suggested by the output coming twice).

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, but that did not give me much clarity on my first question.

Comment: You can place a breakpoint in `draw()` and examine the stack to see the call chain for each call. That should give you a lead on why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where a method has been called from there is an easy trick. Change you `paint` method like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    System.out.println("paint called from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
    if(x==1)
        draw(g);
    else if(x==2)    
        draw2(g);        
}
```

The output will tell you that the call isn't coming from `toBufferedImage` but from a Thread called `AWT-EventQueue-0`:

Here is the output of one of my executions:

```
Start
In constructor
Middle
paint called from AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.Exception
    at Processor.paint(Processor.java:22)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:822)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
In Draw
paint called from main
java.lang.Exception
    at Processor.paint(Processor.java:22)
    at Processor.toBufferedImage(Processor.java:47)
    at Processor.main(Processor.java:57)
In Draw
End
paint called from main
paint called from AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.Exception
    at Processor.paint(Processor.java:22)
    at Processor.toBufferedImage(Processor.java:47)
    at Processor.main(Processor.java:62)
In Draw2
java.lang.Exception
    at Processor.paint(Processor.java:22)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:822)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
In Draw2
paint called from AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.Exception
    at Processor.paint(Processor.java:22)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:822)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
In Draw2
```

BTW: I can see the square you missed.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I was a total beginner to AWT and didn't know that the system generated these calls on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing `draw` methods from two threads: `EventDispatchThread` and `main` thread.

To avoid that, do not call  `setVisible(true)` from the constructor - call it later from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your painting code is wrong.

1. Don't override paint() of a JFrame. But if you ever do, then at a minimum you need a super.paint() to make sure painting is done properly.
2. Painting is done by overriding paintComponent(...) on a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame.
3. Don't invoke paint(...) directly. Swing will create the Graphics object and pass it to the paint() method. Instead you invoke repaint() on the component.

So I can't answer any of your questions about what is happening except to say that the painting is wrong. So do the painting properly and I'm sure the inconsistencies will disappear.

Comment: Great feedback, thanks! Indeed, I am still a beginner to working with AWT and Swing in JAVA. I was simply playing around with the AWT so that I could get some understanding of how it worked. Another question I have-if in my program I must make the next "painting" on basis of the painting I already have, how would I go about that (since I cannot access paint directly)?

Comment: Swing components use methods to change the state of a component. For example when using a JLabel you can use setText(...) or setIcon(...) to change the state. Then the component will invoke repaint() on itself. So in your case you need a method to tell your component to do the next painting.